# How to share information between two public web apps in Azure

Tags: c#, azure-webapps

I have two public web applications running in Azure under the same subscription. WebApp1 is an older application that has been running and serving a limited group of customers for the last two years. WebApp2 will be a fully public web application. WebApp2 needs to send some customer data to WebApp1.

What is the best secure way of doing this?

WebApp1 is already running a couple of webjobs, so WebApp2 could have posted a message to one of the queues which would solve my case. But then two web apps must know how the data to the queue looks like, and the storage credentials must be stored two places.

Event Grid is one option, but is that really necessary?

Create an API in WebApp1 and let WebApp2 post data to the API? How can we prevent others from posting to this API?